# In the Septuagint, 1 Samuel 2:10 has what seems to be a version of Jeremiah 9:23. Modern translations do not have this. Ideas?

Tags: bible, jeremiah, septuagint, samuel

I've been reading the Septuagint recently and noticed that 1 Samuel 2:10 has a version of Jeremiah 9:23 included.  Modern translations do not have this. I'm just looking for reasons.  I guess that ancient Hebrew texts do not include this.

1 Samuel 2:10 NASB

> Those who contend with the LORD will be terrified; Against them He will thunder in the heavens, The LORD will judge the ends of the earth; And He will give strength to His king, And will exalt the horn of His anointed.

1 Samuel 2:10 Brenton LXX

> The Lord will weaken his adversary; the Lord is holy. Let not the wise man boast in his wisdom, nor let the mighty man boast in his strength, and let not the rich man boast in his wealth; but let him that boasts boast in this, to understand and know the Lord, and to execute judgement and justice in the midst of the earth. The Lord has gone up to the heavens, and has thundered: he will judge the extremities of the earth, and he gives strength to our kings, and will exalt the horn of his Christ. And she left him there before the Lord,

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: @EB, Just a heads-up, that the "Christianity SE" is typically more involved in *theology* and *history*. Questions about *Heremeutics* are usually handled over in the "Biblical Hermeneutics" site.  Your Question is *text-critical* though. So it doesn't neatly fit in either site.  So, I hope you don't mind if I tackled it here.

Comment: This is simply one of the many thousands of places where the LXX differs significantly from the Hebrew text.

Comment: I found a scholar who is working on a [critical edition of 2 Sam. in the LXX](https://blogs.helsinki.fi/sacredtexts/2015/10/28/editing-the-septuagint-of-2-samuel/).  He must also be familiar with the issues in 1 Sam as well. You might want to email him: tuukka.kauhanen@helsinki.fi

Comment: Thank you all so much.  All wisdom is very much appreciated.  And 'thank you' also for the heads-up on how better to navigate and participate.

Answer (score 2):

As one looks at the evidence, from a text-critical perspective, this is an example where the LXX translators made a mistake.  I have not found any commentator who goes so far as to give a reason.

The textual evidence is pretty clear.

The witnesses that include the shorter reading are:

1 Samuel 2:10 HMT-W4

> יְהוָ֞ה יֵחַ֣תּוּ מְרִיבוֹ [מְרִיבָ֗יו] עָלוֹ [עָלָיו֙] בַּשָּׁמַ֣יִם יַרְעֵ֔ם יְהוָ֖ה יָדִ֣ין אַפְסֵי־אָ֑רֶץ וְיִתֶּן־עֹ֣ז לְמַלְכּ֔וֹ וְיָרֵ֖ם קֶ֥רֶן מְשִׁיחֽוֹ

1 Samuel 2:10 PESHOT-T

> ܡܪܝܐ ܢܬ݂ܒܪ ܡܡܪ݂̈ܡܪܢܘܗܝ. ܘܥܠܝܗܘܢ ܒܫܡܝܐ ܢܪܥ݂ܡ. ܡܪܝܐ ܢܕܘܢ ܥܒܪ̈ܝܗ݁ ܕܐܪܥܐ. ܘܢܬܠ ܥܘܫܢܐ ܠܡ݁ܠܟܗ݂. ܘܢܪܝ݂ܡ ܩܪܢܐ ܕܡܫܝܚܗ܀܀܁

1 Samuel 2:10 VULG-T

> Dominum formidabunt adversarii eius super ipsos in caelis tonabit Dominus iudicabit fines terrae et dabit imperium regi suo et sublimabit cornu christi sui

So the Masoretic text preserves the shorter reading. The Peshitta does too.  What's interesting is that Jerome, when considering this verse, excised the extra words handed down to him in the Vetus Latina and did not include them in his Vulgate.

The evidence to include the longer reading is as follows:

1 Samuel 2:10 LXXS-T

> Κύριος ἀσθενῆ ποιήσει ἀντίδικον αὐτοῦ· Κύριος ἅγιος. (2·10α) μὴ καυχάσθω ὁ φρόνιμος ἐν τῇ φρονήσει αὐτοῦ, καὶ μὴ καυχάσθω ὁ δυνατὸς ἐν τῇ δυνάμει αὐτοῦ, καὶ μὴ καυχάσθω ὁ πλούσιος ἐν τῷ πλούτῳ αὐτοῦ· (2·10β) ἀλλ’ ἢ ἐν τούτῳ καυχάσθω ὁ καυχώμενος, συνίειν καὶ γινώσκειν τὸν κύριον, καὶ ποιεῖν κρίμα καὶ δικαιοσύνην ἐν μέσῳ τῆς γῆς. Κύριος ἀνέβη εἰς οὐρανούς, καὶ ἐβρόντησεν· αὐτὸς κρινεῖ ἄκρα γῆς. καὶ δίδωσιν ἰσχὺν τοῖς βασιλεῦσιν ἡμῶν, καὶ ὑψώσει κέρας χριστοῦ αὐτοῦ.

1 Samuel 2:10 V-LATINA

> Dominus infirmum facit adversarium eius. Dominus sanctus. Non glorietur prudens in sua prudentia, et non glorietur potens in virtute sua, et non glorietur dives in divitiis suis, sed in hoc glorietur qui gloriatur, intelligere et cognoscere Dominum, et facere iudicium et iustitiam in medio terrae. Dominus ascendit in coelos, et intonuit. Ipse iudicat summa terrae, et dabit fortitudinem regibus nostris, et exaltabit cornu Christi sui …

The LXX and the Vetus Latina (Old Latin) include the longer reading. The witness of the VL is diminished when one considers the fact that, in many instances, the VL was translated from the *Greek*, not the *Hebrew*.

**Conslusion:** The text of the LXX is defective here (as to the parts that were added).

**Consideration:**. This is one of the many examples which show us that the LXX is a *translation*.  Outside of exceedingly few examples where the Versional (non-Hebrew translations) evidence shows us that there's more to consider, the Hebrew text is to be taken as the primary text.  With this in mind, enjoy your readings of the LXX.  In my readings, I've been quite frustrated. For, instance after instance (this would be an example), I found myself wondering, "How did they get that wording?". And, sure enough, when I went back to the Hebrew, it made sense. But then there were examples like this verse, that even when I went back to the Masoretic text, I had no answers as to why the translators did what they did.